# Edge stops showing bookmarks in folders on favorite bar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have this weird behavior in Microsoft Edge on the favorite bar. When I start Edge for the first time in my session I can open a menu folder and choose some link from that menu, I can normally navigate to using those shortcuts. But suddenly (after some clicks, not always after the same click count) the favorite bar stops to show the shortcuts contained in the menu. It shows just an empty rectangle.

If I exit and then restart Edge, this behavior doesn't happen anymore and everything is alright.

Does someone has the same problem?
Does anyone has a fix for this annoying behavior?

Here an image that shows what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problems seem to have gone away the day I replaced my memory sticks. Every day that passed the problem was more and more widespread. Bookmarks faded, the compiler created unstable executables, sudden blue screens, and so on. At that point I decided to do a memory test and many errors came up. The decision to change memory sticks seems to be the solution.